# Imacro search and replace

Tags: imacros

I have  Imacro code, where code first fills the field with some text. I want after fill up the form, it searches each of the already filled form to check some text and if it founds this text in any field, replaces the text string 
Any sugesstion how to do this

[image: Form to process]

First I want to iterate through all the field and check for the string "strong" (in POS 3) and save POS=3

Next delete the string "strong " from POS=3

Please share any idea how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this macro:

```
SET textOut "strong"
SET textIn ""
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO

TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:post ATTR=NAME:answer[] EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=2 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:post ATTR=NAME:answer[] EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=3 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:post ATTR=NAME:answer[] EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=4 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:post ATTR=NAME:answer[] EXTRACT=TXT

SET posNum EVAL("var a = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.split('[EXTRACT]'); for (i in a) if (a[i].match(/{{textOut}}/)) break; ++i;")

SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS={{posNum}} TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:post ATTR=NAME:answer[] EXTRACT=TXT
SET newText EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/{{textOut}}/g, '{{textIn}}').trim();")
TAG POS={{posNum}} TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:post ATTR=NAME:answer[] CONTENT={{newText}}
```

---

**Old info.**

Here is a code to replace some text in the first textarea:

```
SET textOut "abc"
SET textIn "def"
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:post ATTR=NAME:answer[] EXTRACT=TXT
SET newText EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/{{textOut}}/g, '{{textIn}}');")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:post ATTR=NAME:answer[] CONTENT={{newText}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
```

For other fields just change the number of the `POS` parameter.

---

In order to define the position number, you may adjust the following block:

```
SET curPos 1
TAG POS={{curPos}} TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:post ATTR=NAME:answer[] EXTRACT=TXT
SET posNum EVAL("('{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/{{textOut}}/)) ? {{curPos}} : 'NULL';")
PROMPT {{posNum}}
```

Comment: Thanks friend. Is it possible to keep track the POS number in which the desired text occur?. It does not support if/else so I am confused.

Comment: You can use `if/else` statements in the `EVAL` command. See the update.

Comment: Dear friend thank you. If I have four textarea with POS=1,2,3,4 . Does curPos iterate through all POS or not? . Please let me know I am not good at Imacro. First I want to keep track about the POS where the desired string is present and then will iterate through all the POS to delete that desired string . At last i will use the POS number where desired string originally present.

Comment: You can simply write a code in order to make the 'curPos' variable "iterate" through all the `POS`es (`SET curPos 1 ... SET curPos 2 ... SET curPos 3 ... SET curPos 4 ...`). In general, your task explanation is not clear for me. For better understanding, if you wish, provide an obvious example of the issue and how you want to solve it.

Comment: Dear @Shugar I have edited my problem. Please have a look at it.